# how to remove some part till the end in all href links on page

Tags: php, html, regex, url

I have too many links like this on same page i want to remove everything from specified characters till end of that url. Right know i have too many links like this in my page

$amp;rs or &rs is in all links before actual url

```
$string='<td><a href="https://mywebsite.com/book-234-god-is-one&amp;rs=T&amp;pi=DLaLVKLiMIagugSr9YFo&amp;fed=0CBUQ9QEwAA&amp;sdg=AFQjCNHwYLPqh3dXrKGaRucO6diyAt-hjQ"><img src="image.jpg"></a></td>';

                                           or 

$string='<td><a href="https://mywebsite.com/book-234-god-is-one&rs=T&pi=DLaLVKLiMIagugSr9YFo&fed=0CBUQ9QEwAA&sdg=AFQjCNHwYLPqh3dXrKGaRucO6diyAt-hjQ"><img src="image.jpg"></a></td>';
```

I want all links like this:

```
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/book-234-god-is-one"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run an `each` loop on all the `a` tags and modify their `href` attributes:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var newHref = href.replace(/&(amp|rs).*/, '');
    $(this).attr('href', newHref);
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/a7t86md5/)

Comment: thank you all of you for your support but this worked best for me i don't wanted to put extra load on server

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

```
/&(amp|rs)[^"]+/
```

and replace with `''`

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/oE9sE1/1)

Comment: @royleewheels glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below regex and then replace the match by empty string.

```
&(?:amp;)?rs[^"]*
```

**OR**

Use this regex and then replace the match by `\1`

```
(<a href=".*?)&(?:amp;)?rs[^"]*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oE9sE1/2)